# How get page size from MemoryStream or Byte?

Tags: activereports

I have images of active report in database, when i get into bytes and convert into memory stream so it can pass to active report viewer then how i get paper size of paper display in active report?
My code :

```
 Dim repmem As New System.IO.MemoryStream(rptBytes)
 repmem.Position = 0
 Viewer1.Document.Load(repmem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every document page has its own size which could be accessed as:`document.Pages(0).Size`

Answer (score 0):

See the [Page.Width property in the ActiveReports Online Help](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Page~Width.html).
Your code will be something like:

```
 Dim repmem As New System.IO.MemoryStream(rptBytes)
 repmem.Position = 0
 Viewer1.Document.Load(repmem)
 Dim pageWidth as Single
 pageWidth = Viewer1.Document.Pages(0).Width
```